# understanding php directories

Tags: php, html, directory, root

My database config class file is bellow

```
pard_config/class/Config.php
```

pard_config is a folder which is in the root folder.

And i have a json file which contain,host name,database,user and password details

```
pard_config/class/config.json
```

How would i include Config.json file to the Config.php file without reading it from the root.For now i'm doing it like bellow

**Config.php**

```
include("pard_config/class/config.json");
```

Config.json and the config.php files are in the same folder.So is there any way to read from that class folder like bellow **???**

**Config.php**

```
include(config.json);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice you to use a relative path and use the `__DIR__` constant:

```
include(__DIR__ . '/config.json');
```

note that paths will be resolved from the script which where called in browser (or command line) .. like `index.php`. Therefore it will suite better in many cases to use a relative path.